# How to search NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a simple question. How can I search NSMutable Dictionary?
For eg. I have a dictionary like this:

```
      A1: Apple
      B1: Banana
      C1:  Cat
      D1:  Dog
      A2: Aeroplane
      B2: Bottle
      A3: Android
```

Now i want to search all the content (values) whose key starting with letter "A", means I want to search "Apple, Aeroplane and Android". I know how to search array but not Dictionary. Please help me out.

Comment: You cannot assign multiple objects to a single key. It looks like what you're doing at the moment isn't even possible. (Unless your dictionary contains array, but in that case I don't understand what your question is about.)

Comment: @Georg , Yes you r right .... but now I have changed the question. Please see it now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
for (NSString* key in theDictionary) {
   if ([key hasPrefix:@"A"]) {
      // found such a key, do whatever you like e.g.
      [theNewDictionary setObject:[theDictionary objectForKey:key] forKey:key];
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man Its working perfectly. Thanks once again. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't think there's a built-in method for this.

Try:

```
NSMutableArray *results = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

for (NSString *key in [dictionary allKeys]) {
    if ([[key substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"A"]) {
        [results addObject:[dictionary objectForKey:key]];
    }
}

return [results copy];
```

Comment: Hey Tim you are right. You should see the above answer given by Kenny. Its working great for me.. Thanks for your consideration.